# Insert a delimiter between each field of a table and each character in a field

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with 4 fields - name,age,sex,city. Below is the sample data.

[image]

I need to get the output as a single column with values between fields delimited by '-' and the characters within the value delimited by '-'

**Output:   a-b-c-d-3-3-m-a-l-e-p-q-r**

I tried the below query which only delimits the fields .

```
select trim(case when name is not null then name||'-'end ||case when age is not null then age||'-' end ||
case when sex is not null then sex||'-'end || case when city is not null then city end) from table
```

Is there a way to delimit the values within each field as well.

I am using Teradata 16 but if the same is doable in any other RDBMS please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concat all colums first and then use a RegEx to append a dash to each character

```
regexp_replace(coalesce(name,'')||
               coalesce(trim(age),'')||
               coalesce(sex,'')||
               coalesce(city,'')
              ,'(?!^|$)'   -- match every character besides begin and end of line
              ,'\1-')      -- append dash to each match
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select
regexp_replace(name,'\B', '-')||'-'||
regexp_replace(age,'\B', '-')||'-'||
regexp_replace(sex,'\B', '-')||'-'||
regexp_replace(city,'\B', '-')
from table
```

Comment: This is not working as expected . It puts a '-' at the beginning and end of the value , like -abcd- and not within.

Comment: @Abasesha try again

Comment: When I execute for a single column it works fine. But when executed collectively it gives the error- Column or character expression is larger than max size.
I tried creating a new table and saw the data type of the created column and found it to be varchar(24002).  But the data type of each source column of the table I created doesn't exceed varchar(15)

Comment: select
trim(cast(regexp_replace(name,'\B', '-') as varchar(15))||'-'||
cast(regexp_replace(age,'\B', '-') as varchar(15))||'-'||
cast(regexp_replace(sex,'\B', '-') as varchar(15))||'-'||
cast(regexp_replace(city,'\B', '-') as varchar(15)))
from table

Comment: Thank you zhanzezhu for the approach , it was helpful. A simple cast was additionally needed . Not sure why the regex expression multiplied the space for the output.

Comment: The result of REGEXP_REPLACE is a UNICODE VARCHAR(8000), concatenating them hits the limit of 32000. This approach is simpler than mine, but fails if there's any wihitespace like 'a b'

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query. You can use `WHERE` clause instead of case statement.

```
select name||'-'||age||'-'||sex||'-'||city from table
where (trim(name) is not null or trim(age) is not null or trim(sex) is  not nll or 
trim(city) is not null);
```

Or just simply,

```
select name||'-'||age||'-'||sex||'-'||city from table
```

Comment: But this will give me abcd-33-male-pqr. But what I want is a-b-c-d-3-3-m-a-l-e-p-q-r

Comment: Oh you need every character to be delimited?

Comment: Yes  , every character is to be delimited.

Comment: Ok let me check, give me 5 min

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complex solution but it works fine .

```
create or replace function splitjoin(records TEXT[]) returns TEXT[] as $$
declare
cursrow varchar(20) ;
output varchar(30) :='' ;
nums TEXT[] := ARRAY[]::TEXT[];
rec text;
 begin
        FOREACH rec IN ARRAY records LOOP
           FOR counter IN 1..length(rec) BY 1 LOOP
             output=output||'-'||substring(rec,counter,1);
           END LOOP;
         nums =array_append(nums,substring(output,2));
        output='';
      
       END LOOP;
      RETURN nums; 
      end ; $$
     language  plpgsql;
```

Create the above function
and then run the following select command

```
select unnest( splitjoin( (select array(select name||age||sex||city :: text from table  )))::text[]);
```

You are passing array of concatenated records like `{abcd33malepqr,efgh11femaleabc}`
and the result from function is also an array `{a-b-c-d-3-3-m-a-l-e-p-q-r,e-f-g-h-1-1-f-e-m-a-l-e-a-b-c}`  so using unnest in select  for returning records as

```
 a-b-c-d-3-3-m-a-l-e-p-q-r
 e-f-g-h-1-1-f-e-m-a-l-e-a-b-c
```